# How to detech numbers inside a yellow cube with pytesseract

Tags: python, numpy, python-tesseract

So I've ben trying to detect a number (1-9) inside a yellow cube, but without a solid solution..

**This is two of my pictures**

[image: 4]

[image: 6]

This is one solution I've been trying, but without any luck

```py
from PIL import Image
from operator import itemgetter
import numpy as np 
import easyocr
import cv2 
import re
import imutils
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'

img = cv2.imread("ROI_0.png")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thr = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gry, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,
                            cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 59, 88)
bnt = cv2.bitwise_not(thr)
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(bnt, config="--psm 6 digits")
txt = txt.strip().split("\n")
print(txt)
cv2.imshow("bnt", bnt)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Is there another way to do this, because it's not working?

Comment: Have you checked your preprocessed images, thr and bnt? thr is totally black, there is no text in it. and moreover adaptive threshold doesnt work here. It should only be used in case of uneven lighting. Try otsu's binarization and correcting the skew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps:

1. Binarize(otsu's method)
2. Correct skew using minAreaRect
3. Find max area contour
4. crop the number
5. pass cropped to pytesseract

   ```
    image = cv2.imread("y6.png")
    # image = image_resize(image,width=480,height=640)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

    contours = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[0]
    big = max(contours,key=cv2.contourArea)
    (x,y),(w,h),angle = cv2.minAreaRect(big)
    print(angle)

    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
    center = (w // 2, h // 2)
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0)
    rotated = cv2.warpAffine(thresh, M, (w, h),flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,borderValue=(0,0,0))

    big = cv2.findContours(rotated,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[0]
    big = max(big,key=cv2.contourArea)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(big)

    # cropped = rotated[y:y+h,x:x+w]
    cropped = rotated[y:y+h-h//10,w//6:x+w-w//6]

    data = pytesseract.image_to_string(cropped,config='--psm 6 digits')#  -c tessedit_char_whitelist = 0123456789')
    print(data)
   ```

There are a few hardcoded values like h//10 and all in cropping. So optimization is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the black border first for tesseract to work. Just replace the black background with white color and then apply thresholding such that it can remove both white border and yellow color at the same time and then use tesseract to detect the character.